Is there a version of gnome-session-flashback that works with 24.04.1?
I cannot stand the standard gnome interface, so I have habitually used gnome-session-flashback to give me the menus and dock arrangements I like. But after installing ubuntu 24.04.1 and then installing flashback with:
sudo apt install gnome-session-flashback
(and logging out/in, and then rebooting) the flashback menus, etc are not present on screen. Is there some version of flashback (or some equivalent) that works with 24.04.1 ?

Is replacing GNOME as a desktop environment with MATE an option for you? MATE is a clone of GNOME 2.0 so it should have the interface you like. The only issue is that default apps are different in MATE than in GNOME, eg. you have Pluma instead of gedit for text editing, Atril instead of Evince for PDFs etc. If you can get used to this, then MATE is worth trying.
